# Data not displaying in HTML format retrieved from database using PHP

Tags: php

I am having an issue where I am having a user enter information into a textarea and and having that information stored in a mysql database.  The user is allowed to insert HTML into the textarea such as:

```
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

However, I am having trouble seeing why the data that is being retrieved from the database to display the data the user has entered, is not showing the correct HTML format the user requested.

This is what I have:
Displaying the information:

```
<?php
function display ($result) {
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<form action='scripts/submit.php' method='post'>";
      echo "<input type='submit' name='post' value='Post'/>";
      echo " | ";
      echo "<label for='searchDate'>Search Archives By Date:</label>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='searchDate'>";
      echo "<input type='submit' name='submitDate' value='Search'/>";
      echo " | ";
      echo "<label for='searchTicket'>Search Archives By Ticket:</label>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='searchTicket'/>";
      echo "<input type='submit' name='submitTicket' value='Search'/>";
      echo "<hr/>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<table border='1' id='resultTable'>";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $replace = str_replace ("\n","<br/>",$row['content']);
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><span id='boldText'>Entry By:</span> ".$row['user']." | <span id='boldText'>Description:</span> ".$row['description']." | <span id='boldText'>Entry Date:</span> ".$row['date']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<p>".$replace."</p>";
        echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
          echo "<form action='scripts/submit.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='count' value='$row[count]'/>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='edit' value='Edit'/>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'/>";
          echo "</form>";
        echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>";
      }
      else {
        echo "<h3 id='noResults'>Nothing has been posted yet.  Click 'Post' to add something to the whiteboard.</h3>";
        echo "<form action='scripts/submit.php' method='post'>";
          echo "<input type='submit' name='post' value='Post'/>";
        echo "</form>";
      }
}

?>
```

Add Post Logic:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_post'])) {
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);

  $query = "INSERT INTO $table_name (user, description, content)
            VALUES ('$_SESSION[logged_in]','$description', '$content')";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  session_write_close();
  header('Location: ../whiteboard.php');
}
```

For some reason the example above will not work, but this will:

```
<p style="font-weight: 900;">Test</p>
```

Comment: Holy echos, batman. Have you considered [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s or breaking out of PHP mode (`?>`) instead?

Comment: You can't put `<ul>` inside of `<p>`.

Comment: What is being saved to the database i.e. is is actually being saved as HTML code (I know its intended to be, but when you check the database directly, whats there?)? I also agree with @MarcB - you don't need to use php to generate the HTML code, in this example it would be much more convenient to break out of php to use HTML

Comment: @FluffyKitten - Yes, the data is being saved with the HTML in tact:

`<ul>
 <li>Test</li>
</ul>`

Comment: And you say its not showing the correct format - what way is it showing?

Comment: When I try to retrieve the data from the database it does not display the way it was intended to be displayed. i.e. the data is not displaying in an unordered list.

The data is being inserted into the database correctly.  It is just not being displayed back correctly.

Comment: How *is* it being displayed? In paragraphs? All in a single paragraph? Is any formatting being displayed? Examples would help - its difficult to debug a problem without detailed information

Comment: I neglected to think about the css style to reset for browser inconsistencies.  I added a css style for the unordered lists.

Sorry for the waste of post.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing before insert in database using [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) or [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php) and doing the oposite when getting it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing the database entries in a browser, you're going to see the result of the formatted HTML, not the actual markup - use htmlentities($result) if that's what you are after.

View the page source to see what is being retrieved and see how it differs from what you expect to see.